# Media contaner which supports uncompressed audio and video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, format, compression

I want to produce uncompressed video and audio programmatically and feed it via stdin to ffmpeg.
I need uncompressed, because I don't want to encode video and audio in my code.

I found [here](http://zulko.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/read-and-write-video-frames-in-python-using-ffmpeg/) the way to create video only file from uncompressed rgb24 input stream. But I do need to create both video and audio.

Which container supported by ffmpeg can contain uncompressed video and audio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, AVI, MKV and NUT will accept rawvideo and PCM audio streams.